# How to inference Tensorflow model with input queue pipeline?

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, inference, serving

I am struggling with my Tensorflow model. I have trained it using *tf.PaddingFIFOQueue* and then I mainly used this tutorial: https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc#.dykqbzqek, for freezing the graph with its variables and later on loading it into a library for inferencing the model.

My problem is that I don't really know how to run the model for predicting once it is loaded. In the case of just a placeholder as an input it is just required to get the input and output variables and then run the model:

```
# We load the graph
graph_path = ...
graph = load_graph(graph_path)

# We launch a Session
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
  # Note: we didn't initialize/restore anything, everything is stored in the graph_def
  y_out = sess.run(y, feed_dict={
    x: [[3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]] # < 45
  })
  print(y_out) # [[ False ]] Yay, it works!
```

In this example it really looks straightforward but for the use case with input pipeline I didn't really figure out how to make it work. I didn't even find anything related. I some one could give me a hint how this should be done, or how people normally use Tensorflow in production would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit -- do you mean how do you load something in order to replace your 'x: [[3,5,7,....]]' with some real-life testing/validation data? Like from a file?

Comment: Hi, I finally figured out how to make it work. I will write a full answer as soon as I am a bit free as this may be helpful for any starter. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Can you please post how  you solved the problem ? ... that's exactly the same problem I'm stuck into.

Comment: @adam13 Can you please post on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Sure, sorry. I just need to find a free spot! I will prioritize this.

Comment: @adam13 did you write up?

Comment: @adam13 Could you enlighten us on how you resolved this issue?